# Grails form with two submitButton

Tags: forms, grails, action

I have two independent forms that perform the same action, but one should do something more than the other. So, I need to make sure I can know in the controller which `submitButton` called that action in order to process the diferent requests. So my question is:

In a form, with two 
`<g:submitButton name="search" value="More Results"/>`
`<g:submitButton name="searchAndMore" value="More Results"/>`

Is there any way to know which one called the action?

Comment: ups I'm sorry, didn't fint it at first but then there it is the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740439/get-name-of-clicked-submit-button-in-grails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, your submit button will be present as a request parameter with the same name and value as the button in the markup:

```
params.search == "More Results"
```

or

```
params.searchAndMore == "More Results"
```

You could also check using:

```
if (params.containsKey('search'))
// or
if (params.search)
```

Answer (score 1):

May be helpful :

```
<g:form>
  ...
  <g:actionSubmit action="search" value="Search"/>
  <g:actionSubmit action="searchAndMore" value="More Results"/>
</g:form>
```

Comment: He's going to the same action rather than two different actions. However, maybe this answer will inspire a different controller design.